# How do the parasitic elements behave in a bidirectional power switch made from back-to-back MOSFETs?

Tags: power, mosfet, switches, bidirectional, parasitic-capacitance

I would like to know how to determine the value of the total internal gate mesh resistor (Rg) and different parasitic capacitors especially Cgs and feedback capacitor Cds of a bidirectional power switch build by two back-to-back MOSFETs (with common source). What about the Miller plateau? I am interested in the switching behavior of such kind of power switch in order to define a proper dead time of a multilevel power inverter.
thanks

Comment: Simulators are the likely tool for this. Try one.

Comment: Be sure your SPICE model includes all the important parasitic elements. If you have not yet learned to read those models, now is the time to learn.

Comment: I am using Infineon CoolMOS CFD7 MOSFETs (IPP60R070CFD7), Model Level 0. This model includes most of the parasitic elements, the other levels take into consideration the transient, switching losses, self heating, heat flow and thermal model..